# How to use Selenium with Python to save an array of links to images to my computer

Tags: python, arrays, image, selenium, save

So right now, I am using Selenium in conjunction with urllib to populate a list of links to images. So say I have this array:

```
image_links = {"http://www.link.com/image.jpg", "http://wwww.link.com/image2.jpg", "http://wwww.link.com/image3.jpg", "http://wwww.link.com/image4.jpg", "http://wwww.link.com/image5.jpg", "http://wwww.link.com/image6.jpg", ...etc}
```

So, the current code that I have is:

```
namecount = 0

for il in image_links:
    if(il is not ""):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(il, r"C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Images\Image_" + str(nameCount) + ".jpg")
        nameCount += 1
```

The problem I'm getting is an error saying:

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

After research on the Internet, I have came to the conclusion that my program is trying to save the file before it actually loads. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this?

Complete code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import ijson
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import urllib

import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui




save_amount = 2
fetch_amount = 10
parser = ijson.parse(urlopen("http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/P250%20%7C%20Mint%20Kimono%20%28Factory%20New%29/render/?query=&start=0&count=100&country=US&language=english&currency=1&filter=%22Mint%20Kimono%22"))

image_links = []

links = []
ids = []
flinks = []
fids = []

inspect = []

for o in parser:

string = str(o)

if ("market_actions.item.link" in string):
    links.append(o)


elif (".id', 'string', '" in string):
    ids.append(o)

for l in links:
string = str(l)

index = string.find("'string'")

index += 11

flinks.append(str(l)[index:-2])

for i in ids:
string = str(i)

index = string.find("'string'")

index += 11

fids.append(str(i)[index:-2])

count = 0;

while (count < 200):

if ("%listingid%" in flinks[count]) and ("%assetid%" not in flinks[count]):

    inspect.append(flinks[count].replace("%listingid%", fids[count]))



elif ("%listingid%" not in flinks[count]) and ("%assetid%" in flinks[count]):

    inspect.append(flinks[count].replace("%assetid%", fids[count]))

count += 1

chromedriver = "C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://metjm.net/csgo/web/")

count = 0

while (count < fetch_amount):
sbox = driver.find_element_by_id("manualEnterTextbox")
print(sbox.text)

sbox.send_keys(inspect[count])

submit = driver.find_element_by_id("manuelEnterOkButton")
submit.click()

count += 1


while(len(image_links) < save_amount + 1):


open_links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("openImageButton")


for li in open_links:
    bgi = li.get_attribute("style")
    bgi_fixed = bgi[23:-3]

    if bgi_fixed not in image_links:

        print(bgi_fixed)
        image_links.append(str(bgi_fixed))

time.sleep(0.5)



nameCount = 0


for il in image_links:

if(il is not ""):

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(il, r"C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Metjms\MintKimono_" + str(nameCount) + ".jpg")

    nameCount += 1
```

Complete Error Traceback

[Gyazo Link To Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z79Zk.png)

Comment: Please post the complete code and the complete error traceback. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I have added the complete code and a link to a picture of the complete error traceback!